# Jquery how to get a hiddeninput given a data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes with class mycheckbox and a html5 attribute position.

For every checkbox of this class that is checked I want to get the related hidden input with class header that has the same html5 attribute value for data-position. I want to make a list of the values of the hiddenfields.

So a checkbox would look like this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" data-position="@item.Position"/>
```

and a hidden input would look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" data-position="@item.Position" />
```

So I came up with:

```
$('input:checkbox.mycheckbox:checked').each(function () {
   var position = $(this).data('position');
   $('input:hidden.header[data-position=need somehow to get position in here]').each(function () {



   });

 });
```

So I'm unsure how to specify the position value from the checkbox in the search for the hidden elements and also how to set the values from each hidden field to a list

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this:

```
$('input:hidden.header[data-position="' + position + '"]').each(function () {
```